# How to pass data between React components without rendering the child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I'm trying to get data from my textService into the Error500Page without rendering the Error500Page. How can you pass state data as props without rendering the child component?

I'm trying to do this but it doesn't seem to work very well.

This is my code in the parent class

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      url:"",
      data: [],
      isLoaded: false,
      test: "Will it work?",
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchImg(process.env.REACT_APP_TEXT_API);
    this.passError500();
  }


  fetchImg(url){
    const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
    fetch(proxyurl+url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded:true,
          data:json,
          test: "Will it work?",
        })
      })

  }
  passError500(){
    return(
      <Error500Page test={this.state.test}/>
      )

  }
```

And this is how I try to access the props in the child class

```
import TextService from 'src/app/services/textService/textService';

const Error500Page = (props) =>
{

  console.log(props.test);
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col flex-1 items-center justify-center p-16">

            <div className="max-w-512 text-center">

                <FuseAnimate animation="transition.expandIn" delay={100}>
                    <Typography variant="h1" color="inherit" className="font-medium mb-16">
                      {props.test}
                    </Typography>
                </FuseAnimate>
```

When I console log props.test I get undefined. Any idea how can I make this work? Thanks

Comment: You need to call `this.passError500()` after you change the state (after `this.state.test` is set), you can do that in the `render` method or use something like this: `this.setState({ ..... test: "Will it work?"}, this.passError500)`

Comment: I don`t want to render the component in that class.

Comment: You can call the function in `render` without rendering the component.

Comment: When will `Error500Page` get rendered?

Comment: It doesn`t work. Neither with the call back after the setState or with the function in the render.

Comment: Let me see if I understood correctly. You want to access a `prop` without render the component? This is a weird use case. Could you show us why would you ever need to that?

Comment: @ravibagul91 when the application load. I want the data to be there from the beginning.

Comment: I don't think React works that way. To see the passed prop you need to render the child component. If you don't render the child component and after that manually try to go to that component, how the React will know which parent injected what prop?

Comment: @Dupocas I want the service to load some data from the API call in the Error500 page. The data comes from the back-end. I want to do so because the back end has a dashboard where non tehnical people can modify the text.

Comment: I am confused here, when you want to render `Error500Page` component?

Answer (score 0):

Try it access the props with `this.props`

```
const Error500Page = (this.props) =>
```

Comment: The component is stateless so you don't need "this". Will throw " Cannot read property 'props' of undefined" if you use the "this" keyword.

Comment: So why don't you use a functional component

Comment: What do you mean by a functional component?

Comment: Functional components are new since the React 16.8 Hooks update ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll get what you want with this:

```html
export function Error500Page(test) {
   

    return <div className="flex flex-col flex-1 items-center justify-center p-16">

            <div className="max-w-512 text-center">

                <FuseAnimate animation="transition.expandIn" delay={100}>
                    <Typography variant="h1" color="inherit" className="font-medium mb-16">
                      {test}
                    </Typography>
                </FuseAnimate>;

}
export default { Error500Page };
```

```
 passError500(){
    return(
     Error500Page(this.state.test)
      )

  }
```

Comment: And make sure you are using the newest react version